# Modified model in node.js not reflecting on MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I just modified my model *Order* for my API because I need a value to pass a condition. But unfortunately, my new set of properties (*orderStatus*) on my collection did not reflect on my MongoDB database.

I don't need to input a value for the property (*orderStatus*) since I set a default value ("*Pending*"). I tried to delete the entire collection *orders* to see any changes but there were none. Is there something else I need to do on my MongoDB or any command on the git?

Here is my code for my model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userId: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "User ID is required!"]
    },
    products: [
        {   
            productId: {
                type: String,
                required: [true, "Product ID is required!"]
            },
            quantity: {
                type: Number,
                required: [true, "Quantity is required!"],
                min: 1,
                default: 1
            },
            subtotal: {
                type: Number,
                required: [true, "Subtotal is required"],
                default: 0 
            }
        }
    ],
    totalAmount: {
        type: Number,
        required: [true, "Total Amount is required!"],
        default: 0
    },
    orderStatus: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Order Status is required!"],
        default:"Pending"
    },
    purchasedOn: {
        type: Date,
        default: new Date
    }

});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Order", orderSchema);
```

and a screenshot of my database

[image: and a screenshot of my database]

I will really appreciate your help! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your documents which were already created will not reflect your new schema field. Since those fields only will get reflected on the update only. So, add `orderStatus` as pending as the default. You must migrate those documents by the update method. This is going to be a one-time process.

**So, in the terminal, you can write the following code and run**

```
db.collection.update({}, {$set: {orderStatus: "Pending"}}, {upsert: true, muti: true})
```

**Or you are comfortable with the code itself you can write your update code in your project itself like this**

```
await orderModel.updateMany({}, {$set: {orderStatus: "Pending"}}, {upsert: true})
```

and make an API and call this code.

In this process, you will see that in your documents that new key called orderStatus with pending value has been created.

Comment: Hi @Rakesh! Thank you so much! I did the terminal code using Robo3T. My pre-exisiting document as well as my newly created documents are already updated with my new schema! Thanks again!